# Error "Could not load file or assembly" returning again and again

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll, filenotfoundexception

Recently we've changed one of the assemblies (Kendo.MVC) and after this from time to time I get an exception "Could not load file or assembly 'Kendo.MVC, Version=xxx Culture=xxx PublicKeyToken=xxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Removing and adding the reference to this assembly helps to run the project. However, it helps only for the short time, after some particular changes (for instance, web.config is changed) the exception returns. Same with "rebuilding all" - it helps, but only temporary. Versions, etc looks to be correct too. Which is quite confusing.

I looked at the project file and all references are in place and are the same both when it works and when it doesn't.

Neither in Module window, nor in Debug Output window I see something suspicious, at least no errors.

What might be wrong? Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use [fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.100).aspx) to get more insight in why binding fails

Comment: @rene, thanks for the advise! However, Assembly binding Log Viewer doesn't show my error. I used default seetings for it - but nothing, it is empty, even though I run application and see the error in the browser.

Comment: Run your webapplication in an appdomain with your identity...configure a custom log folder

Comment: Use the vendor's support forum: http://www.kendoui.com/forums.aspx